# Script fails when form selection GT 9

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Would love some help here. I'm sure it's simple enough, I'm just a bit flummaxed by it.

This script I am working on: http://jsfiddle.net/rVPnu/9/ fails when the selection is greater than 9.

**Can someone explain why and how I fix this so if I select 11 it shows 11 divs?**

I did notice this line in the code:

```
// var gh = tee.charAt(tee.length-1);  // get the int form id will (fail if GT 9)
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `var gh = tee.slice(-1);`. It takes the last character of the elements ID, which in the case of the 11th select is `npup10` and returns `0`.

If all elements are going to start with npup you could instead do `tee.slice(4)`.